# Saving image to media library WP7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I cant save images into windows phone media library ! Here is my code snippet :

```
public void SaveImageTo(string fileName) 
    {
        fileName += ".jpg";
        var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (myStore.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            myStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
        }

        IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(fileName);                       

        // Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
        myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();

        library.SavePicture(fileName, myFileStream);
    }
```

Please give some suggestion !
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ....

```
public void SaveImageTo(string fileName = "ShareByQR.jpg") 
    {
        fileName += ".jpg";
        var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (myStore.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            myStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
        }

        IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(fileName);
        WritableBitmap wr = imageControl; // give the image source
        wr.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, wr.PixelWidth, wr.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
        myFileStream.Close();

        // Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
        myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        //byte[] buffer = ToByteArray(qrImage);
        library.SavePicture(fileName, myFileStream);
    }
```

hope it works!

Comment: that's great! if exception occurs you should see the stack trace !

Comment: I dont understand this line WritableBitmap wr = imageControl; // give the image source

Comment: What is imageControl;

Comment: @V.G. I referred to <Image/> of XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I changed Shishir's snippet to read extern url.
This is my method :

```
    public void SaveImageTo(string fileName = "SO.jpg")
    {
        string source = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFN0.jpg";
        Uri url;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(source, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
        {
            WriteableBitmap wr;
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(url);
            img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
            // When image is ready, show must go on.
            img.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
            {
                wr = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)s);
                //fileName += ".jpg"; // we dont need that
                var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                if (myStore.FileExists(fileName))
                {
                    myStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
                }
                IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(fileName);
                //WriteableBitmap wr = img; // image source already given
                wr.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, wr.PixelWidth, wr.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
                myFileStream.Close();

                // Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
                myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
                //byte[] buffer = ToByteArray(qrImage);
                library.SavePicture(fileName, myFileStream);
            };
        }
    }
```

Dont forget to add ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO in WMAppManifest.xml .
I hope this can help too.