# Hold gesture to save image to media library

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to work something out and can't seem to get the final piece together. I have a Windows Phone app that displays images from Flickr and what I want to do is allow the user to save the image that is on the phone screen to their Media Library. I've employed the Hold Gesture to do this and I need some help getting the context menu to pop-up after the user holds down on the image. I'm not sure how to get the menu to pop up. Here is the Hold-Code I'm trying to use. There is something I'm missing here.

```
private void Image_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var img = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Image;

        var url = (string)img.Tag;

    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to save an `Image` to the `MediaLibrary` on Windows Phone 7 and 8.

There are...

1. [Blogs with code snippets](http://code-examplez.blogspot.ie/2011/04/saving-images-to-media-library-on.html)
2. [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx)
3. [Lots of previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11288044/247257) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Okay thanks. But one more question... Does isolated storage increase the size of "disk space" on the phone because it is saving all of the images in my photostream to a users phone? -after the image is stored in isolated storage the user can save it to the media library, but in the meantime the images are also stored in folders of the app - increasing the apps size.  This is why using the Hold Gesture was recommended to me, so the user could save whatever image they selected. The photostream has about 75+ images in the stream currently and increases monthly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Saving the image to `IsolatedStorage` will increase the disk space usage of your app, but once the image is saved to the `MediaLibrary`, you can delete the copy of the image in `IsolatedStorage`, so your usage will not increase over time.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to have some type of responsibility with streaming these pictures and allowing users to save them to their phones.

Comment: You can always download similar apps from the store and see how they function, but it's always good to think about network data usage and phone storage.