# How to get a picture in Media Library with its full address

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

After user chooses an image in `PhotoChooserTask`, I get file name from `e.OriginalFileName` something like this:

> C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Saved Pictures\Fantasia Painting(1).jpg

I don't need it's stream, but want to be able to find it in `MediaLibrary`. How can I find an image with above address in MediaLibrary? thanks

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to check whether the image is in MediaLibrary? Or do you want to save the image into it?

Comment: @RajeevNair both of them.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether an image is in the Media library:

Instantiate MediaLibrary object (use necessary namespaces)

```
MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();
```

The following will give the count of images with names containing "Fantasia Painting":

```
lib.Pictures.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Fantasia Painting")).ToList().Count;
```

To save an image to the Media Library:

[Saving image to media library WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288017/saving-image-to-media-library-wp7)